# Http: URL para subir archivos a onedrive con java

Tags: java, url, https

Estoy intentando subir archivos a mi cuenta [Onedrive](https://onedrive.live.com/about/es-es/).

En el ejemplo que tengo en el Service es:

```
https://independentsoft-my.sharepoint.com/personal/info_independentsoft_onmicrosoft_com
```

> El problema, que tengo, es que según entiendo, esta URL es de
>   Business, pero en mi caso, en el que mi OneDrive es personal, **cuál
>   debería ser la URL**? Gracias

Comment: echa un vistazo, quizá te ayude https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/01636d9b-7b8e-4a62-b95f-ff8f33615e37/how-can-i-get-the-personal-siteonedrive-for-business-url-?forum=sharepointgeneral

Comment: ok, muchas gracias! lo miro ahora mismo

Comment: me da la sensación que para uno personal no hay URL, si no que tiene q ser un bussiness (pero tampoco sé del tema). Suerte de todos modos!!

Comment: a mi también me da que tampoco se puede, he probado varias maneras y buscado pero no aparece nada, es más, un compañero con el que lo he hablado probó y al final le tuvieron que dar la URL de la empresa a la que se le estaba haciendo el proyecto.

Comment: Sí que tiene toda la pinta. https://d.docs.live.net/YOUR-CID
De todos modos, echa un ojo a esta tb, que me da que a partir del ID  sí que llegan  https://www.thurrott.com/cloud/microsoft-consumer-services/onedrive/3638/onedrive-tip-map-your-cloud-storage-as-a-drive-in-file-explorer